# What does "which" refer to in the context?

Tags: meaning

What does "which" refer to in the following sentence?

> The final jurisdiction over what an intellectual is resides in culture, which becomes almost coterminous with a singular public opinion.(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ja/dictionary/english/coterminous)

I think it refers to an intellectual, but I'm not sure.

Comment: _An intellectual_ refers to a person, so it would have to be _who_. I think it must refer to _culture_.

Comment: **which** could refer to the fact that culture is 'where' the determination is made. What is culture?  "a singular public opinion", sorta.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. I actually lacked a basic knowledge that an intellectual refers to a person, but my excuse is that "comma which" confused me. And now I understand what "which" refers to, still the meaning of the sentence will take a while to sink in for an English learner like me, but anyway I really appreciate your kindness, Kate.

Comment: It's is not a lucid sentence.

Comment: @yatterman If you want someone to be notified of your comment to them, put `@` before their handle. There's automatic name completion when you do this, so type `@t<tab>`.

Comment: @TimR, I realized that I did not know what culture really means and that is why I could not understand the sentence. Thank you teacher.

Comment: When the subject is "Who gets to decide what an *intellectual* is?" the interested audience is a very small one, a sub-culture :-)